# Seleccionar grupos que no cumplan condiciones especificas

Tags: sql, select, condiciones, count

Estoy intentando obtener todos los grupos y sus contadores que no cumplan una condición especifica, existe forma de hacerlo en una sola query?

Tabla

```
1    2
A    X
B    Y    
C    Y 
A    Y 
B    Y
```

Hasta ahora mi query para agrupar todos sería:

```
SELECT 1,COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM Tabla GROUP BY cnt
```

En mi lógica si hago un `WHERE 2 != X` solo se reduciría en 1 el `COUNT` de la columna 1 y lo que requiero es excluir a todo el grupo A si cuenta aunque sea solo una X en la columna 2.

Gracias por adelantado.

Update:
Pongo mas info para que se pueda entender mejor mi problema:

Tabla:

```
lvl  info
1   A
2   B
3   A
1   A
2   A
3   A
```

Al realizar `SELECT lvl,COUNT(lvl) AS count FROM table GROUP BY lvl`
obtenemos los siguientes resultados:

```
lvl   count
1       2
2       2
3       2
```

Lo que quiero hacer es buscar la forma de descartar por completo el grupo que no cumpla una condición especifica, en este hipotetico caso, si `info == B` descartar todo el grupo al que pertenezca quedando como resultado de la query anterior unicamente:

```
lvl   count
1       2
3       2
```

El problema:
Solo he podido lograr que se descarte un solo miembro del grupo que cumpla la condición con la siguiente query `SELECT lvl,COUNT(lvl) AS count FROM table  WHERE info NOT IN (B) GROUP BY lvl` quedando como resultado:

```
 lvl   count
  1       2
  2       1
  3       2
```

Espero se pueda entender mejor ahora.

Comment: Qué sería el resultado que quisieras obtener? puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Obtener los grupos que no cumplan con una condición, es decir, si tan solo un solo miembro de dicho grupo cumple el tener la variable X, descartaría al grupo completo de la query final)
Hasta ahora solo se me ocurre esta query:  `SELECT 1,COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM Tabla WHERE 2 != 'X' GROUP BY cnt`, donde según mi logica solo descarta 1 miembro del grupo y no al grupo completo per se.

Comment: De verdad no logro hacerme a la idea ni de cuales son tus datos de entrada ni de lo que quieres obtener. Sugiero que añadas unos datos de ejemplo de lo que habría en `Tabla` y cuál es el resultado que esperas que tu consulta te de para esos datos de ejemplo. Un slaudo.

Comment: @Winebous por favor pon la estructura de las tablas y el resultado esperado dentro del post, de otro modo creo que es muy difícil entender lo que quieres

Comment: Añadida mas info al problema, gracias por su paciencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver con un query anidado asi:

```
    SELECT lvl,COUNT(lvl) AS count FROM table 
    WHERE lvl not in (SELECT lvl FROM table WHERE info == 'B') GROUP BY lvl
```

Comment: Esplendido, muchas gracias